# Excel Calculating Issue

Tags: excel

I know this question is a long shot, but hopefully someone can help.

I have an Excel workbook with thousands of formulas that take a long time to calculate. The file is stored on a shared network, so I can access it from multiple PCs (PC 1 and PC 2). When I use PC 1, I am able to click my mouse anywhere in the workbook and the file immediately loads and completes the calculations afterwards. When I use PC 2, clicking the mouse does nothing. Excel doesn't acknowledge the click, and you have to wait for all calculations to be complete before being able to use the workbook.

Is there a way to implement this mouse-click feature on PC 2?

All settings in Excel are the same on both PCs.

Comment: Calculating settings are computer specific vs file specific. Make sure the settings on both are the same - if not, update PC 2 calc setting to match PC 1 and save file. This is by design of course as it stops your excel from automatically adopting other peoples settings that you may disagree with.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Calculation Option to manual (under formulas bar) then it will not automatically calculate and you can calculate it manually from that bar or by hitting F5.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you set calculation to manual then the information is not up to date and you might be working with old or incorrect data.